# What sort of problems yield validation warnings when parsing a XML document using a XSD schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am trying to reacquaint myself with XML documents and schemas (XSD), but I am having trouble understanding what sort of XML document issues would yield a `XmlSeverityType.Warning`.

Taking [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371(v=vs.110).aspx) as an example, what would I need to change in the XML document (or XSD schema) to force a warning to appear?

Comment: Documentation more or less describes that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlseveritytype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Evk Yes, I saw that. It is a given that it would cover non-error conditions so I didn't find the information provided particularly fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

[As @Evk commented](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk), the [**documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlseveritytype(v=vs.110).aspx) for `XmlSeverityType.Warning` states:

> **Warning**    Indicates that a validation event occurred that is not an error. A warning is typically issued when there is no DTD, or XML
>   Schema to validate a particular element or attribute against. Unlike
>   errors, warnings do not throw an exception if there is no validation
>   event handler.

Therefore, it's not so much what to change in your XML or XSD but what you might change to cause your XSD not to be found for your XML, i.e. perturbing (or deleting) the following line in your source:

```
settings.Schemas.Add("http://www.contoso.com/books", "contosoBooks.xsd");
```

It's possible that the .NET XSD processor has opted to present additional diagnostics beyond those required by the [W3C XSD Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) or [W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) (see also [**valid vs well-formed**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)), but the only change mentioned in the documentation pertains to validation request that cannot be fulfilled due to a missing schema.

Comment: That just throws an exception for me - doesn't hit the warning code

Comment: Warnings are generated for children of elements with an `xs:any` XML Schema definition without `xsi:type` and without a _Salami Slice_ XSD design pattern containing a matching `xs:element` definition which makes them undefined.